# I cannot understand how the filter method works in this function

Tags: javascript

There is a function designed to clear an array of duplicate characters

```
let x = [55, 44, 55, 30, 30]
let unique = x.filter((e, i) => x.indexOf(e) === i )

console.log(unique)
```

The first value of the filter is responsible for the current processed element in the array, the second is the index of the current processed element in the array, as far as I understand, in the function we use indexOf, we compare two indices of the same number (indexOf (e) and i), but how -that way to filter the array, we still get it, how?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it using sentences?

Comment: [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the smallest index of a found item. that means you get the items with the smallest index - and of course in this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) documentation says:

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

This is what you'll see in the execution:

```
e=55, i=0: indexOf(55) is 0 === 0: true!
e=44, i=1: indexOf(44) is 1 === 1: true!
e=55, i=2: indexOf(55) is 0 !== 2: false! 
e=30, i=3: indexOf(30) is 3 === 3: true!
e=30, i=4: indexOf(30) is 3 !== 4: false!
```

Your output will only include the `true` results, after items 2 and 4 are removed:

```
[55, 44, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` always returns the index of the **first appearance** of your input. This is why this filter function works.

In the case of your example, `let x = [55, 44, 55, 30, 30]`, `x.indexOf(55)` would yield `0`. Do you see why this filters out any other occurrences of `55`?